# How to send error message from preSignUp trigger in cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am verifying the already exists email using listUsers function in the preSignUp trigger in cognito. When I send a callback to Cognito(callback(`Email Already Exists`)). This displays PreSignUp failed with Email Already exists instead I want to display only 'Email Already Exists'.
Any help is appreciated.